# Append JSON from deep nested value to top level with jq

Tags: json, bash, sed, jq, etl

Here is some sample data:
https://gist.github.com/dmc2015/19fc41aa677ba02a3bc49c53057ce408

Every script I have below should work, but I don't know how to combine them.
I need to do the following:

- change a key name
- be able to select specific keys to return, I don't need them all
- be able to select and parse values
- turn parsed values in to key value pairs and add them back in to the json

### Change a key name

```
jq '.cards[] | select(.closed == false) | with_entries(if .key == "id" then .key = "trello_id" else . end) | .' data.json
```

returns:

```
{
  "trello_id": "1234",
  ...
  ..
}
```

### Select specific keys to return

```
jq '.cards[] | with_entries(select([.key] | inside(["name", "description"]) ) ) | .' data.json
```

returns:

```
{
  "desc": "*Important Notes* ",
  "name": "Housing - Lawrence"
}
```

### Query & Parse Values to create my own keys

```
jq '.cards[] |
.checklists[] | select(.name == "Acct Information") |
  .checkItems[] | select(.name | contains ("Location")) |
  .name | .'  data.json |
    cut -d ":" -f 1 |  sed 's/"//g' |  sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/' | sed -r 's/\s+/_/g'
```

returns: `location_address`

```
jq '.cards[] | .checklists[] | select(.name == "Acct Information") |
.checkItems[] | select(.name | contains ("Location")) |
  .name | .'  data.json |
  cut -d ":" -f 2 |
    sed -e 's/\"//g' -e 's/*//g'
```

returns `"123 Hopscotch Way"`

I can do most parts individually but I am struggling to see a way to do it all in one query.
This is something close to the end result that I want.

```
    [
      {
        "trello_id": "1234",
        "desc": "*Important Notes* ",
        "name": "Housing - Lawrence"
        "location_address": "123 Hopscotch Way"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Post the original JSON and an exact expected output as JSON as well

Comment: One of the reasons why you should do as @Inian has requested (though if the original JSON is large, please prune it in accorance with the [mcve] guidelines) is that it is evident that a very simple solution should be possible using jq, but it is difficult to explain without an example.

Comment: And your jq command works or doesn't? Please provide a [mre]. NB `|.` is redundant and can be left out from any jq program.

Comment: edited with data sample @Inian

Comment: @peak I added data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could something like this be what you are looking for?

```bash
.cards | map(
  select(.closed == false) | {trello_id: .id, desc, name} + ([
    .checklists[] | select(.name == "Acct Information")
    | .checkItems[].name | select(contains("Location"))
    | capture("(?<key>[^:]*):\\s*(?<value>.*)")
    | .key |= (gsub("\\s+"; "_") | ascii_downcase)
    | .value |= gsub("\\*"; "")
  ] | from_entries)
)
```

```json
[
  {
    "trello_id": "1234",
    "desc": "*Important Notes* ",
    "name": "Housing - Lawrence",
    "location_address": "123 Hopscotch Way"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/o4JkIhWNdGz)